# Métodos estáticos equivalem à funções?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, funções, métodos-estáticos

Em OOP temos os métodos estáticos (não dependem de nenhuma variável de instância). Citando exemplos:

```
class Somar {
    public static function soma($a,$b){
        return $a+$b;
    }
}
echo Somar::soma(20,30);
```

O equivalente do método *static* da programação OOP são as *functions* normais da programação estruturada?

```
    function soma($a,$b){
        return $a+$b;
    }

 echo soma(20,30);
```

Ou seja, as *functions* da programação estruturada são *statics*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, as funções funcionam como os métodos estáticos, a diferença é que o método está encapsulado em uma classe, o que evita conflito de nomes que é mais comum em funções soltas. Apesar do termo usado, isto sequer é o encapsulamento de verdade que observamos em OOP.

Uma função tem [visibilidade e escopo global](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) igual ao método estático (embora este possa eventualmente ter sua visibilidade limitada por outro mecanismo).

Tecnicamente um método estático nada tem a ver com OOP. Na verdade o fato de usar uma classe não significa que está fazendo algo OOP. Para dizer que é OOP precisa existir outras características no código.

Na verdade a única diferença entre um método estático e um de instância é que o de instância possui um parâmetro oculto na sintaxe chamado `$this` e esta variável dá acesso aos membros do objeto. Se não existisse a facilidade de sintaxe, um método de instância:

```
function exemplo($p1, $p2) {}
```

Deveria ser escrito assim:

```
function exemplo($this, $p1, $p2) {}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/StaticMethod.php).

E obteria o mesmo resultado, pelo menos do ponto de vista de acesso à instância.

Ou seja, na verdade todos métodos são funções.

Comment: Python é um bom exemplo disso, onde não existe esse Syntax Sugar para o contexto, que no caso do Python, é o "self".