# Quando utilizar métodos estáticos?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou trabalhando em um projeto e como base estou utilizando outro para referência. Porém, neste outro projeto quase todos os métodos estão declarados como `static`.

Isso é uma boa prática?

Quais são as vantagens ou desvantagens que tenho em declarar um método como static?

Comment: [É uma má prática usar apenas métodos estáticos numa classe?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/115473/91), [Quando faz sentido ter apenas métodos e atributos estáticos em uma classe?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129983/91) e [Principal objetivo de classes utilitárias](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90047/91)

Comment: Pergunta duplicada do próprio Stackoverflow. 
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12651/quando-devemos-declarar-um-m%C3%A9todo-como-est%C3%A1tico

Comment: Valeu pelas referências. Mas após ler tudo isso eu ainda fico em dúvida. Porque segundo eles n é má pratica. E tem ganhos consideraveis em alguns casos. Mas nunca tinha visto um sistema inteiro assim. Então pra mim a primeira vista parece n ser correto criar um sistema inteiro com metodos static!

Comment: Se ainda tem um dúvida específica, faça a pergunta sobre essa dúvida de forma específica (algum ponto bem específico não respondido). O que foi perguntado já está bem respondido nessas outras perguntas. Você também pode colocar uma recompensa em uma delas pedindo mais detalhes.

Comment: Mais: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/54012/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/103796/101, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/123974/101,

Comment: Valeu @bigown! Estou bem mais esclarecido agora e vejo q n terei problemas em utilizar metodos estáticos. :)

Comment: Depende de como utilizar, sim, em outros casos, não

Comment: Sim. Eu ainda pretendo estudar um pouco mais afundo orientação a objetos para me esclarecer mais e aplicar melhor os conceitos.